# I get a syntax error when I import discord in the cmd but not in vs code

Tags: python, discord

I get a syntax error when I try to import discord, everything works in vscode but not in cmd

> C:\Users\Tirterra\Documents\Python\pythonProject\Event bot>main.py
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "C:\Users\Tirterra\Documents\Python\pythonProject\Event bot\main.py", line 4, in 
> import discord
> File "C:\Users\Tirterra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord_*init*_.py", line 25, in 
> from .client import Client
> File "C:\Users\Tirterra\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 959
> """
> ^
> SyntaxError: (unicode error) \N escapes not supported (can't load unicodedata module)

and my code is just

```
import discord
```

Comment: You need to put the error's text in your question rather than having a screenshot of it.

Comment: ok I edited my question

Comment: You appear to be running the wrong Python version.

Comment: it works in vs code and I didn't cahnge anything to the version or something

Comment: when I print(sys.version") it says that I am in 3.8.5 so I really don't see why it doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I first oppened the discord module and changed the code where the error occured, there was an issue with the '\N' not being in a substring,but I also got a new error :/(that had nothing to do with discord module).The _socket module was nowhere to be found so just reinstall python.