# Keep getting syntax error for: async def on_ready():

Tags: python, discord.py

I am trying to make a Discord bot with this code, however I get this error in the terminal. I know about [I get a syntax error when I import discord in the cmd but not in vs code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64491461/i-get-a-syntax-error-when-i-import-discord-in-the-cmd-but-not-in-vs-code), but it does not solve the issue I am having.

```
from discord.ext import commands
from utils.logger import Logger

logger = Logger().logger
glados_cores = ["cogs.angry_core"]
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")
bot.logger = logger


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    logger.info("---------------bot-ready---------------")
    logger.info("Hello and, again, welcome to the Aperture Science computer-aided enrichment center.")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    for extension in glados_cores:
        try:
            bot.load_extension(extension)
        except Exception as e:
            exc = f"{type(e).__name__}: {e}"
            logger.info(f"{exc} Failed to load extension {extension}")

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

I keep getting this syntax error when I try to run the code:

```
COMPUTER:Genetic-Lifeform-and-Disk-Operating-System-master COMPUTER$ python main.py
  File "main.py", line 11
    async def on_ready():
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python \[Invalid syntax\] with async def](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43948454/python-invalid-syntax-with-async-def)

Comment: @RandomDavis No, I already looked at that thread.

Comment: So what version of Python are you running this on?

Comment: @RandomDavis 3.9.1

Comment: Actually 2.7.16

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens if you do not have python 3.5+. If you get a syntax error in cmd it's likely because you have python <3.5 installed on your path.

Comment: I have python 3.9.1

Comment: But are you sure thats what you're using to run the bot?

Comment: Wait. You are right. I just checked and I have python version 2.7.16 and don't have pip installed. I think I may have multiple python version installed. A while ago I had a problem with python and pip, so I uninstalled python and pip manually by deleting their folders. My system is probably very confused by everything, how do I fix this?

Comment: I have 2.7.16 not 3.9.1

Comment: @AleksandarVasilic you could just use `python3` instead of `python` to run scripts. Or alias the command, like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18425379/how-to-set-pythons-default-version-to-3-x-on-os-x).

Comment: Easy way to change it is to just reinstall python 3 and make it install on your path